# Media Server Plugin in Grails

Tags: grails, video-streaming, grails-plugin

I want to implement a simple media server using Grails which streams video albums to users. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks,
Reza

Comment: Hello, have you done your media server? I would to implement one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GVPS plugin looks like your best bet: http://grails.org/plugin/gvps